# Installing gems and fixing incompatibilities

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rubymine

I've recently installed the latest version of RubyMine, along with Ruby 1.9.3-- that's the version we're on at work.

When I open RubyMine and try to set the SDK to 1.9.3 I'm prompted to update some gems, but then receive errors I can't figure out what to do with.  Would anyone know what's going on here and what I can do to fix it?  (I do have the latest version of DevKit installed, and in my path.)

```
mini_magick (3.6.0): While executing gem ... (Errno::EINVAL) Invalid argument - C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mini_magick-3.6.0/test/files/special! "chars'.gif diff-lcs (1.2.4): 

Error installing diff-lcs: "htmldiff" from diff-lcs conflicts with C:/Ruby193/bin/htmldiff bson (2.0.0.rc1): 

Error installing bson: Building native extensions. This could take a while... ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
```

..there are about four more errors for various other gems.

I have Ruby and RubyMine working fine on another box, also on 1.9.3, but can't figure out what might be going on in this instance.

Comment: Are you sure DevKit was installed correctly and works? Does the [test step from the guide](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit#5-test-installation) work for you?

Comment: Yes, I checked those steps and everything looked good.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working eventually, by doing removing gems by hand and re-adding them.  Not really sure what the final, victorious, step was but doing the previous often enough got all the gems added properly.